# Java jxl reading template?

Tags: java, jxl

I am trying to load my excel template i want to change with this method. but each time i run my application it wil give me the next error:

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void Savefile() throws WriteException, IOException, BiffException {
    WritableWorkbook workbook = null;
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    FileChooser fileChooser1 = new FileChooser();
    File file = fileChooser1.showSaveDialog(stage);
    System.out.println(file);

    try {
        File template = new File("C:\\Users\\Bart\\Desktop\\Factuur.xlsx");
        Workbook workbook1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(template);
        WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, workbook1);
        WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(0);

        jxl.write.Label label = new jxl.write.Label(0, 13, "A label record");
        sheet.addCell(label);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AlatasController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is the inner exception of the InvocationTargetException? (InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor)